# How to represent infinity in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, infinity

Is there a way to represent infinity (as a float/double, or NSNumber, etc.) in Objective-C? In other words, is there a float/double/NSNumber value that is always larger than any other value in Objective-C?

Comment: IEEE floating point (both 32 and 64 bit versions) has a defined value for "infinity".  As Adrian indicates, there is a pre-defined macro in Objective-C to access this value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a macro for this `INFINITY`,

```
float x = INFINITY;
```

You can find this in usr/include/math.h

```
#   define    HUGE_VALF    __builtin_huge_valf()
...
#define INFINITY    HUGE_VALF
```

**Edit** Some more interesting read here

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html